# How to decode and save a file sent to php from js

Tags: php, file-upload, base64, filereader

I have a drag and drop uploader. I am using File Reader to send data As url.

```
    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    var start = 0;
    var stop = files[0].size - 1;
    var reader2 = new FileReader();
    var ext = f.name.substring(f.name.indexOf(".")+1);
    reader2.onloadend = function(evt) {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
            $.post("/process/upload.php",{"blob":evt.target.result,"extension":ext},function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    };
var blob = f.slice(start, stop + 1);
reader2.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
```

PHP recieves it but once I decode it I get "null" returned

```
$extension = $_POST['extension'];
$file = base64_decode($_POST['blob']);
$filePath = "../tmp/monkey.".$extension;
echo json_encode(base64_decode($_POST['blob']));
```

I also tried:

```
if(file_put_contents($filePath,$file)){
    echo json_encode("it worked");
}else{
    echo json_encode("it failed");
}
```

EDIT: I maintain the POST info all the way until I decode it. So once I decode it how do I determine the file is intact and can be saved?

Is there a better way to decode and save file?
What exactly am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST['extension']` and `$_POST['blob']` don't magically get populated into `$_POST` array when posting in JSON format. In fact based on your JSON format, the JSON will decode into an object, not an array.

You will need to get the contents directly from input like this:

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_obj = json_decode($post);
$extension = $post_obj->extension;
$file = base64_decode($post_obj->blob);
```

Or using `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` variable like:

```
$post_obj = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
$extension = $post_obj->extension;
$file = base64_decode($post_obj->blob);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I tried both versions and I'm still getting null or an empty string.

Comment: What value is giving null?  Can you `var_dump($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, file_get_contents('php://input'))` to see if you are getting what is expected there?

Comment: when I echo file_get_contents('php://input'); I get the base64 + the extension, when i echo $file I get an empty string. When I echo $post_obj i get Null.

Comment: You shouldn't be `echo`ing these variables, but rather `var_dump`ing them to get an understanding for what values they really hold. Perhaps your JSON is not well formed (this would return `NULL` when attempting to `json_decode`)

Comment: I'm echo ing just to see if something exists. My javascript is up there, do you see anything that may be incorrect?

Comment: ok, Now that I used var_dump I see what your suggesting. I'm getting string(44134) followed by strange characters. I'm guessing this is the decoded file. So what is the best way to save that file?

Comment: My guess is it might need to be encoded on the javascript side of things

Comment: I figured it out. It wasn't the js nor my php above. using var_dump was actually the tool i used to solve it. I appreciate your help.